# Some tasks those insert data into mongodb taking a long time in spark streaming

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application that fetches log records from Kafka and inserts all the access log records into mongodb. The application runs normally in the first few batches,but after some batches there appears some tasks in a job takes quite a long time to insert data into mongodb.I guess it should be a problem with my mongodb connection pool configuration, but I have tried changing quite a lot with no promotion.

Here are the results from web ui:

[time takes for each job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8v5B.png)

[time takes for abnormal tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJXQW.png)

Spark: version-1.5.1 on yarn (well,this may be really too old.)

Mongodb: version 3.4.4 running on four machines with 12 shards.Each machine is 160G+ and 40 CPUs.
Codes for mongodb connection pool:

```
private MongoManager() {
        if (mongoClient == null) {
            MongoClientOptions.Builder build = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
            build.connectionsPerHost(200);
            build.socketTimeout(1000);
            build.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(200);
            build.maxWaitTime(1000 * 60 * 2);
            build.connectTimeout(1000 * 60 * 1);
            build.writeConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
            MongoClientOptions myOptions = build.build();
            try {
                ServerAddress serverAddress1 = new ServerAddress(ip1, 20000);
                ServerAddress serverAddress2 = new ServerAddress(ip2, 20000);
                ServerAddress serverAddress3 = new ServerAddress(ip3, 20000);
                ServerAddress serverAddress4 = new ServerAddress(ip4, 20000);
                List<ServerAddress> lists = new ArrayList<>(8);
                lists.add(serverAddress1);
                lists.add(serverAddress2);
                lists.add(serverAddress3);
                lists.add(serverAddress4);
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(lists, myOptions);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void inSertBatch(String dbName, String collectionName, List<DBObject> jsons) {
            if (jsons == null || jsons.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
            DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
            dbCollection.insert(jsons);
        }
```

And the spark streaming code are as below:

```
referDstream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
    val records = partition.map(x => {
      val data = x._1.split("_")
      val dbObject: DBObject = new BasicDBObject()
      dbObject.put("xxx","xxx")
      ...
      dbObject
    }).toList
    val mg: MongoManager = MongoManager.getInstance()
    mg.inSertBatch("dbname", "colname", records.asJava)
  })
})
```

Script to submit application:

```
nohup ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --name ${jobname} --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 8g 
--num-executors 20 --executor-memory 16g --executor-cores 4
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" --conf "spark.shuffle.manager=hash" 
--conf "spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true" --driver-java-options "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" 
--master ${master} --class  ${APP_MAIN}  --jars ${jars_path:1}  ${APP_HOME}/${MAINJAR} ${sparkconf} &
```

Data obtained from mongo shell:

```
$ mongostat -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20000
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize  res faults qrw arw net_in net_out conn                time
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0    14|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   985b   19.4k   58 Dec  7 03:10:52.949
  2999    *0     *0     *0       0     8|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   517b   17.6k   58 Dec  7 03:10:53.950
 15000    *0     *0     *0       0    19|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   402b   17.2k   58 Dec  7 03:10:54.950
 17799    *0     *0     *0       0    22|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0  30.5m   16.9k   58 Dec  7 03:10:55.950
 15996    *0     *0     *0       0    18|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   343b   16.9k   58 Dec  7 03:10:56.950
 12003    *0     *0     *0       0    26|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   982b   19.3k   58 Dec  7 03:10:57.949
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     6|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0   518b   17.6k   58 Dec  7 03:10:58.949
  4704    *0     *0     *0       0     8|0       0     0B 1.17G 514M      0 0|0 0|0  10.2m   17.1k   58 Dec  7 03:10:59.950
 34600    *0     *0     *0       0    64|0       0     0B 1.17G 526M      0 0|0 0|0  26.9m   16.9k   58 Dec  7 03:11:00.951
 33129    *0     *0     *0       0    36|0       0     0B 1.17G 526M      0 0|0 0|0   344b   17.0k   58 Dec  7 03:11:01.949

mongos> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 57, "available" : 19943, "totalCreated" : 2707 }
```

Thanks for any suggestion about how to solve this problem.